# Grub - multiple distros

Tags: grub2

I had Ubuntu 12.04 BETA installed on my entire HD. Then I decided to also install Linux Mint Debian Edition 121204 (LMDE).

1. With gparted I shrunk my /home to make room for one more distro
2. I created the partitions needed for LMDE, but figured I could use the same swap
3. I installed LMDE - no errors. During install I selected to install GRUB to /dev/sda

   - Grub shows Linux Mint Debian Edition, but no sign of Ubuntu
   - The new LMDE install will not boot
   - I can use LMDE from USB stick, which is what I use right now
   - My Ubuntu /home has data that is not backed up (must recover)

If I can boot back into Ubuntu to back up I am OK again. Please help.

```
From gparted (sda8 and sda9 is the new ones after shrinking sda7)
/dev/sda1   ext4        20 GB  Flags: boot
/dev/sda2   extended   912 GB
  dev/sda5    ext4        20 GB
  dev/sda6    linux-swap   4 GB
  dev/sda7    ext4       585 GB
  dev/sda8    ext4        20 GB
  dev/sda9    ext4       285 GB
```

Answer (score 0):

Recovering your /home should be easy with your Live USB, simply mount the partition and copy to an external HDD. As for editing GRUB, hopefully someone else can help.